# Is there a way to delete data from a specific point of a file?

Tags: c, fatfs

I'm using Chan's FatFS (http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) in C and I'm trying to delete all the following lines from a specific point of a file. I've set the filepointer to my new "End of file", the rest of the file should be deleted/discarded/what ever. 
I'm searching for a way around a temporary file. Is there a solution like putting a '\0' at the new end of a C-String? (I know that EOF isn't a character anymore)

Comment: How about `f_truncate`? It is clearly listed in the API. Did you read it?

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer by myself, but I will still answer my own question to avoid other people getting into my situation.

There's a function in Chan's FatFS to truncate the file:

```
FRESULT f_truncate(FIL* fp);
```

http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/truncate.html